# Find consumer gain

Tags: economics

Both demand and surplus functions are linear. Demand function is as following : $Qd = 400 - 10P$. Equilibrium quantity is 200 units. Find the consumer gain

I tried to solve it this way:
First I found P : $$Qd = 400 - 10P$$
                  $$10P=400$$ 
                  $$P=40$$
Then we have a formula : $$CG = 1/2(B*H)$$
As I have equilibrium 200 then my B is $$400/2=200$$
                               my H is $$40/2=20$$
So $CG= 1/2(20*400)=2000$
But I`m not sure about this answer, could you answer is it correct and if not where am I wrong.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: What is a surplus function in this context?

Comment: @callculus i don`t know. I wrote all the data I was given. And I should explain at the end what I have found but to be honest I don`t have any ideas what 2000 is